# Node.js about architecture and development of simple webapp

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mobile, web-applications

I've been reading about Node.js hoping to expand my web development skills.

Now I don't quite understand how I will use it to develop my own mini-project, **what I'm trying to achieve is to have, say, a html webpage (www.example.com/routine/video.php) that will display a series of videos**.

I would like to **then have another html webpage say(www.example.com/routine/controller.php) that will have a button that will pause/unpause the video thats currently playing on video.php.** (why do I need another html page?, because my goal is to have like a remote controller inside a mobile device, it might even add a login to this working experience and after the login that will lead me to the controller.php page and while on my monitor the video.php will be playing, I can pause and unpause with my phone using controller.php).

Another thing that I don't quite understand is, I would like video.php be like dynamic with for example 3 videos(v1,v2,v3), and open it on monitor1, then have another monitor open that same webpage and run other 3 videos (v4,v5,v6) all working like parallel. **(maybe using some ids for the post? video.php?type=sequence1)**

Some people have told me to use node.js, but the video.php cannot be dynamic because if I understood correctly the js creates a server with a ip and a port, and I cannot create multiple servers on the same port.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just some comments:

1. It doesn't matter if you using PHP, Node.js, or even Ruby if you want to make certain type of apps, they eventually can be built, just using different implementations.
2. Node.js essentially allows you to write server side code in JavaScript, so that you can just use 1 language for front-end and back-end.
3. You probably will need to look at web socket to realize your 'remote' functionality. (think about a live chat app.) Some idea would be you can streaming your video via a readable stream, and your app provide an API to control how it would response by watching the change of states.
4. You may want to lookup some Node frameworks, such as Express.js to save your time.
5. I don't understand why you say 'video.php' can not be dynamic (BTW, in Node.js you don't need `.php`, the idea between PHP and Node.js is totally different).  And of course, 1 port can only serve 1 server, because you don't want multiple server against one another.

IMO, I'll assume you just adapted Node.js from PHP, so I will suggest you to look how Node.js is different than PHP, and try to build an normal website (such as a forum, blog or something similar). Your 'mini project' is actually not 'mini' at all, it requires you to leverage many concepts (e.g. readable/writable stream, etc.)...

Comment: Oh I see, Yeah im more of a php-js guy, but I would like this to work with node if possible, what I meant with your 5 point is, the same instance but doing different things and yes, I usually try to do a hard try with new tech so I can dominate it quickly.

Comment: That is nice, I will suggest try webSocket.  For more info, try out `https://socket.io`.  Your app is essentially a live chat twist, so you will need streaming, which is a big highlight in Node.

Comment: Yeah but I was thinking this morning, what if I want to have like, 2 parallel "video.php", I was checking socket.io, and It seems that, If i want 2 video feeds, I would have to create another server and work with that, because If I have only 1 video.php showing 2 different videos the same time and I pause one of them, it will stop all of them.

Comment: Not necessary.  Although I don't understand what your 'parallel' means, but it just like to create 2 chat rooms.  Your server will generate streams on demand.  Node.js is non-blocking stacks, so it can server multiple user simultaneously without worry too much performance issues (although what I'm saying about performance here is a bit ambiguous, but you get my point).

Comment: I understand you, I did my research and I think socket.io is my best bet, but can't I mix it with my php and mysql code? maybe making the login all with php+ js, then it redirects to the socket.io server webpage? would be that done in the right way?

Comment: In theory, you can handle the authentication in a different server, and send the authentication as a token via a HTTP header to Node server.  But it may double the work and introduce more complicity.  In some scenario, you actually want to do this in a subdomain, usually for a security reason.  Or, that say you have an old app and want to extend the functionality in a new server.  It depends on your situation though.